# unable to update table using JSP/DAO/Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dao

Hello i'm trying to create a page to update a row in my database table i'm using DAO/Servlet with JSP page

DAO code:

```
public static AnimalUpdateBean updateAnimal(AnimalUpdateBean bean) {

          //preparing some objects for connection 
        PreparedStatement up = null;   
        Statement stmt = null;    

          String id = bean.getAnimalId();
          String aname = bean.getAnimalName();
          String dob = bean.getAnimalDob();  
          String gender = bean.getAnimalGender();  
          String breedid = bean.getAnimalBreed();  
          String remark = bean.getAnimalRemark();
          try 
           { 
            //connect to DB 
              currentCon = dbConnection.getConnection();

              up = currentCon.prepareStatement("update animal set aname = '"+aname+"' , gender = '"+gender+"', specie_id = '"
                      +breedid+"' , remark = '"+remark+"' where animal_id = '"+id+"'");

              up.executeUpdate();

              if (up.executeUpdate()>=1){
                  stmt=currentCon.createStatement();
                  rs = stmt.executeQuery("select aname , dob, gender, specie_id , remark from animal where animal_id = '"+id+"'");
              }


          System.out.println("done");
       }


       catch (Exception ex) 
       {
          System.out.println("Log In failed: An Exception has occurred! " + ex);
       } 

       //some exception handling
       finally 
       {
          if (rs != null)   {try {rs.close();} catch (Exception e) {} rs = null;}

          if (stmt != null) {try {stmt.close();} catch (Exception e) {}stmt = null;}

          if (currentCon != null) {try {currentCon.close();} catch (Exception e) {}currentCon = null;}
       }

    return bean;

       }    
   }
```

UpdateAnimal.jsp code:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@page import="content.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page session="true"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" 
         contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
         pageEncoding="windows-1256" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<title>Update Animal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Zoo keeper</th></tr>
</table>


<h1>Update Animal</h1>

<form action="Relay" >
<fieldset>
Animal new name: <input type= "text" name = "aname"><br>
Animal new DOB: <input type= "text" name = "dob"><br>

<br>
Animal new gender: 
<select name="gender" id="gender">
<option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<br>

Animal new Breed: <input type= "text" name = "breedid" ><br>
Animal new remarks: <textarea name = "remark" rows="4" cols="20">

</textarea> <br /> <br/>


<input type="submit" value="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="animal_id" value="<%= request.getParameter("animal_id") %>">
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="UpdateAnimalServlet" > 

</fieldset>
</form>
</body></html>
```

the record being updated come from a select page to view the records when the user click on the name he will be redirected to update page CheckAnimal.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@page import="content.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page session="true"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" 
         contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
         pageEncoding="windows-1256" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<title>Animal list</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Zoo keeper</th></tr>
</table>


<h1>Animal list</h1>
Click on animal name to update it!
 <center>
 <table width="100 % " id='table1'  border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"> 
    <tr class="tab-highlighted-2"> 

        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="15"> 
          <div align="left">Name</div> 
        </td> 
        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="13"> 
          <div align="left">Age</div> 
        </td>
         <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="13"> 
          <div align="left">Gender</div> 
        </td>
        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="13"> 
          <div align="left">Status</div> 
        </td>    
        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="13"> 
          <div align="left">Breed</div> 
        </td>  
        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="13"> 
          <div align="left">Pen #</div> 
        </td> 
        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="15"> 
          <div align="left">Zoo</div> 
        </td> 
        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="20"> 
          <div align="left">Remarks</div> 
        </td> 

    </tr> 

    <c:forEach items="${beans}" var="view"> 
        <tr> 

            <td><a href="/oosd/UpdateAnimal.jsp?animal_id=${view.animalId}&breed=${view.breedId}">${view.animalName}</a></td>  
            <td>${view.animalDob}</td>
            <td>${view.animalGender}</td>
            <td>${view.animalSource}</td>
            <td>${view.animalBreed}</td>
            <td>${view.sectionId}</td>
            <td>${view.zooId}</td>
            <td>${view.animalRemark}</td>

        </tr> 
    </c:forEach> 
</table> 

         </center>

</body></html>
```

AnimalUpdateBean.java code:

```
package content;

public class AnimalUpdateBean {
    private String animalId;
    private String animalName;
    private String animalDob;
    private String animalGender;
    private String animalBreed;
    private String animalRemark;

    public String getAnimalId() {return animalId;}
    public String getAnimalName() {return animalName;}
    public String getAnimalDob() {return animalDob;}
    public String getAnimalGender() {return animalGender;}
    public String getAnimalBreed() {return animalBreed;}
    public String getAnimalRemark() {return animalRemark;}

    public void setAnimalId(String animalId) {this.animalId = animalId;}
    public void setAnimalName(String animalName) {this.animalName = animalName;}
    public void setAnimalDob(String animalDob) {this.animalDob = animalDob;}
    public void setAnimalGender(String animalGender) {this.animalGender = animalGender;}
    public void setAnimalBreed(String animalBreed) {this.animalBreed = animalBreed;}
    public void setAnimalRemark(String animalRemark) {this.animalRemark = animalRemark;}


}
```

the servlet responsible to start the update is UpdateAnimalServlet:

```
package content;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
public class UpdateAnimalServlet extends HttpServlet {


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                       throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

try
{       

     AnimalUpdateBean animal = new AnimalUpdateBean();
     animal.setAnimalId(request.getParameter("animal_id"));
     animal.setAnimalName(request.getParameter("aname"));
 //    animal.setAnimalDob(request.getParameter("dob"));
     animal.setAnimalGender(request.getParameter("gender"));
     animal.setAnimalBreed(request.getParameter("breedid"));
     animal.setAnimalRemark(request.getParameter("remark"));
     String test = request.getParameter("animal_id");
     System.out.println(test);
     System.out.println(animal);

     animal = DAO.updateAnimal(animal);


          response.sendRedirect("/oosd/member.jsp"); 


} 


catch (Throwable theException)      
{
     System.out.println(theException); 
}
       }
    }
```

I'm using a Relay servlet that calls AnimalUpdateServlet for execution:

```
package content;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
public class Relay extends HttpServlet {


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                       throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

    try
    {       



        String command = request.getParameter("command");  
        if (command.equals("LoginServlet")){ 
            RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("/"+command);
            rd.forward(request, response);
            //for testing 
            System.out.println("Request forwarded to " + command + " servlet"); 
        } else if (command.equals("UpdateAnimalServlet")){ 
            RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("/"+command);
            rd.forward(request, response);
            //for testing 
            System.out.println("Request forwarded to " + command + " servlet"); 
        } 

        else 
            System.out.println("=> command='" + command + "'");  
            String url = "/oosd/" + command;     
            String encodedUrl = response.encodeRedirectURL(url);   
            System.out.println("   url=" + url);    
            System.out.println("   encodedUrl=" + encodedUrl);  
            response.sendRedirect(encodedUrl);



    } 


    catch (Throwable theException)      
    {
         System.out.println(theException); 
    }
           }
        }


and last thing is the web.xml page:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>content.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UpdateAnimalServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>content.UpdateAnimalServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SelectAnimalServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>content.SelectAnimalServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Relay</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>content.Relay</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SelectAnimalServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SelectAnimalServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UpdateAnimalServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UpdateAnimalServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Relay</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Relay</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I keep getting these errors:
Log In failed: An Exception has occurred! java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed

I have checked the data entry and all correct name text, gender text, specie_id number, remark text i even put the dob on hold until this work i'm using access database and here is the connection code:

```
package content;


import java.sql.*;


public class dbConnection {

   static Connection con;
   static String url;

   public static Connection getConnection()
   {

      try
      {
         String url = "jdbc:odbc:oosd"; 
         // assuming "DataSource" is your DataSource name

         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

         try
         {              
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"",""); 

         // assuming your SQL Server's  username is "username"               
         // and password is "password"

         }

         catch (SQLException ex)
         {
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

      catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
      {
         System.out.println(e);
      }

   return con;
}
}
```

Any idea where is my mistake here ?

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't need any of those import directives in your JSP if you're not writing any scriptlet code (which you're not, and shouldn't be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as specie_id  is a number and that's what the thrown exception is stating "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." and because of this exception sendRedirect error is occuring as because of the SQLException data has been already written to the response.
 your query should be something like

```
  "update animal set aname = '"+aname+"' , gender = '"+gender+"', specie_id = "
                  +Integer.parseInt(breedid)+" , remark = '"+remark+"' where animal_id = '"+id+"'"
```

same would be required if animal_id is also a number.

Comment: could you provide the schema of animal table

Comment: what exactly do you want ? because access generated shcema is sorta huge

Comment: can you check in the debugger what is the update query being executed on db ? try executing that query via sqldeveloper/SQL+ or any other GUI tool which you use if its not working just Fix the query and the code accordingly

Comment: i removed the single qoutes around the values and now i'm getting 

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2.

Comment: you have to remove single quotes only for those field which are number's in DB

Comment: indeed i have it's updated now i only need to get rid of java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4769/discussion-between-dhirendra-and-user1031152)

Answer (score 0):

The `sendRedirect` error happens when you've already written data to the response (like with a forward, or to the JSP writer directly) then try to redirect.

The SQL error is likely due to you using a string IDs in the SQL (surrounded by single-quotes) whereas the IDs in the DB are most likely defined as an integer.

Also, after you update the animal, you perform a query, but do nothing with the results.

Comment: i removed the single qoutes around the values and now i'm getting 

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2.

Comment: it's updated now i only need to get rid of java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed error

Comment: @user1031152 There's too much code for me to go through. Something is writing to the response, either via a forward (like a JSP) or direct writes to the output stream. Once that happens, you can't send a redirect.